# Drawing stock chart with DataPointCollection.DataBindY in C#

Tags: c#, charts, candlestick-chart

How can I draw a stock chart with List<> and DataPointCollection.DataBindY at once?

I know how to add stock data on a chart but I don't want looping and repeating drawing by Add because actual list is much longer.

To draw a chart at once I tried DataPointCollection.DataBindY but it doesn't work. It needs IEnumerable[] but I don't know how to change List<> to IEnumerable[].

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double[] Candle;

    List<double[]> CandleList = new List<double[]>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Candle = new double[] { 5, 0, 3, 1 };

        CandleList.Add(Candle);

        Candle = new double[] { 10, 5, 7, 9 };

        CandleList.Add(Candle);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CandleList.Count; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(CandleList[i]); // works well
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(CandleList); // System.ArgumentException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a list is an iEnumerable, iEnumerable[] means an array of lists.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<double>[] Lists = new List<double>[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Lists[i] = new List<double>();
    }

    Lists[0].Add(5); // high
    Lists[0].Add(10);

    Lists[1].Add(0); // low
    Lists[1].Add(5);

    Lists[2].Add(3); // close
    Lists[2].Add(8);

    Lists[3].Add(2); // open
    Lists[3].Add(7);

    chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(Lists);
}
```